# autohotkey show main window command

Tags: window, command, program-entry-point, autohotkey

At the end of my AutoHotKey scripts, I like to put in a pause hotkey for debugging.  I would also like to pop up the AHK main window to view lines most recently executed.  I couldn't find this script command.  Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotkey Command for displaying a list of most recently executed lines is:
ListLines seen here: [List Lines AHK Documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ListLines.htm)